# How to de-optimize the Linux kernel to and compile it with -O0?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, kernel

I'm wanting to read and understand the Linux kernel's Memory Management (in particular defrag\compaction\migration).

So, I turn off optimization for size in `.config` (using make menuconfig of course) and compile...This leaves me with still an optimized kernel.

**NOTE:** When I say optimized kernel, I mean that when I use `gdb` and tell it `next` that it'll jump around. I don't want that, I want to be able to follow the code line by line just as I would with a simple hello world.

Next, I edit the `Makefile` and swap `-O2` with `-O0` and that causes things to break.

I found [this](http://niaz-debugging.blogspot.dk/2012/01/disable-optimization-for-some-files-in.html), but I don't know what files I'll want because I don't know how far down the rabbit hole goes.

Is there a more generic option that I can use? I understand the concepts of memory compaction; however, I want to see where everything happens and how it exactly happens.

Comment: How are you `gdb`ing the kernel? Do you have `kgdb` support turned on?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm going through `qemu -s` in `DEBUG_KERNEL` is enabled. I'll enable `kgdb` and report the results.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Although I couldn't get a pipe working with qemu (gdb threw fits), there doesn't seem to be a difference.

Comment: While going through the question above, I'm suddenly curious, why Linux kernel has to be optimized for working properly?

Comment: @osgx it's not a kdb issue that I was having in regards to EugeneSh. it is a qemu issue.

Comment: Greg says it can't be done, thus you can't be done (in practice): https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2016-August/016689.html :-) Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153788/linux-cannot-compile-without-gcc-optimizations-implications

Answer (score 17):

You can't de-optimize the kernel.  You might be able to de-optimize certain functions, like this:

```
void __attribute__((optimize("O0"))) foo(unsigned char data) {
    // unmodifiable compiler code
}
```

But the kernel as a whole requires -O2 because the code itself is written with assumptions that certain functions will be optimized in a certain way.

Sorry, but you really will need to know the size of the rabbit hole you want to go down.

Comment: Can we set optimization as `-O1` instead `-O0`?

Comment: „But the kernel as a whole requires -O2 because the code itself is written with assumptions that certain functions will be optimized in a certain way.“ – That sounds ugly.